# .htaccess redirect everything to new domain except one URL to something different

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am 301 redirecting everything from `http://something.org/*` to `https://something.com/*` with this code...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.something.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am trying to add exception that this URL `http://something.org/registration/service` redirects to `http://www.something.com/registration/service` (not HTTPS like general rule). Tried this to exclude this url from general rule and it works, but I don't know how to add rule to redirect this exclusion to something else:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/registration/service
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.dewesoft.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your RewriteCond with this :

```
RewriteRule ^registration/service http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Nope... Rewrites into this `https://www.something.com/http://www.something.com/registration/service/service`....

Comment: Please be more specific about the issue you are having with this.

Comment: I think my question is more or less clear what I want to do... The issue with your suggestion is that id doesn't work. I have replaced my RewriteCond line as you suggested with your code. When I enter this into the browser `http://example.org/registration/service ` it rewrites into `https://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/registrat‌​ion/service/service`.

Comment: It doesnt rewrite it just redirects a specific request to http version of a diffrent site. I have tested it and it works fine.